# Ajax security using SpringMVC and jQuery

Tags: jquery, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and Spring MVC with jQuery. My Spring Security is pretty basic setup based on the Spring Security reference docs. I'm using Spring 3.2.4.

```
<http use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/denied" access="permitAll" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?authFailed=true"> 
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login.html" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" /> -->
    <form-login login-page="/secure/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/secure/denied" />
    <logout logout-url="/secure/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    <expression-handler ref="defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="com.ia.security.SpringSecurityDao" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="com.ia.security.SpringSecurityDao" class="com.ia.security.SpringSecurityDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value>select username,password,enabled 
        from user 
        where username = ?
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value>SELECT R.ID, R.NAME, P.NAME
            FROM ROLE R
            JOIN USER_ROLE UR on R.id = UR.role_id
            JOIN USER U on U.id = UR.user_id
            JOIN ROLE_PERMISSION RP ON RP.role_id = R.id
            JOIN PERMISSION P ON P.id = RP.permission_id
            WHERE U.username=?
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Under normal circumstances, everything runs properly.  I can request my page via jQuery.ajax and my callback works as expected.  However, I do not know how to set things up to handle session-timeout or unauthorized access responses.

For example, if a session times out, and I continue to make an Ajax request, Spring Security redirects the call to the login page.  So the response to the ajax request ends up being a login page.  On the client side, I need to be able to know that the user no longer has access to the requested page and take appropriate action - ie: redirect the browser to a login/error page.  The same holds true if the user does not have permissions to access a url.

I've found similar posts that relate to how to configure logins via ajax, but am having trouble understanding how to deal with unauthorized requests via ajax.  I presume that in the case of Ajax calls, the server should return a specific Status Code (ex: 401 unauthorized, etc), and have the JS handle the difference codes, but am not sure where/how to configure that information.

I've tried looking at the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` classes, but they do not seem to even be used in my configuration (setting breakpoints in them are not even hit), so I'm really at a loss to understand what/how/where to configure the necessary handlers/filters/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using access-denied-handler in your http tag something like this

```
<http auto-config="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
```

```
<bean id="accessDeniedHandler" 
class="CustomAccessDeniedHandler">
<property name="accessDeniedUrl" value="acessDenied" />
```

You can create your own Handler implementing Spring’s AccessDeniedHandler and then  override handle() method.

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

   private String accessDeniedUrl;

    public String getAccessDeniedUrl() {
    return accessDeniedUrl;
}

public void setAccessDeniedUrl(String accessDeniedUrl) {
    this.accessDeniedUrl = accessDeniedUrl;
}

@Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
    ServletException {

      // Your own logic something like this

   response.sendRedirect(accessDeniedUrl);
   request.getSession().setAttribute("message",
    "You do not have permission to access this page!");

}
```

}

accesDenied.jsp can be something like this

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied</h1>
<h3>Message : ${message}</h3>       
</body>
</html>
```